# Firebase Cloud Function not executing Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have the following function in my index.ts file:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const db = admin.firestore();
const fcm = admin.messaging();


export const sendToDevice = functions.firestore
      .document('orders/{orderId}')
      .onCreate(async snapshot => {
        print("aa")
        console.log("osakosak");
        const order = snapshot.data();
    
        const querySnapshot = await db
          .collection('users')
          .doc(order.ustaID)
          .collection('tokens')
          .get();
    
        const tokens = querySnapshot.docs.map(snap => snap.id);
    
        const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
          notification: {
            title: 'New Order!',
            body: `you sold a ${order.day} for ${order.time}`,
            click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
          }
        };
    
        return fcm.sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
      });
```

However, when the new document gets added into the order collection, this doesn't get triggered. Even the print and console.log don't work. I tried putting print and console log before export, and it still didn't fire.

Comment: Since [version 1.0](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#new_initialization_syntax_for_firebase-admin), you should initialize `firebase-admin` as folllows: `admin.initializeApp();`

Comment: I changed it, but the outcome was the same @RenaudTarnec

Comment: You don't see `console.log("osakosak");`in the log?

Comment: Nope, not when the app starts nor when the document is created

Comment: Is the Cloud Function correctly deployed. What do you see in the Cloud Function console? In the Google Cloud console?

Comment: I just noticed that I don't have the Cloud Functions API installed in my Google Cloud Console, may that be the problem?

Comment: How did you deploy the Cloud Function?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec i depended on cloud_firestore in pubspec.yaml

Comment: Cloud Functions are totally independent from your Flutter app. It is a back-end service. You should deploy it with the Firebase CLI, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#deploy-functions-to-a-production-environment  The code shall be in the Firebase Project, not in your Flutter project.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec oh i see, thanks a lot. Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments ("It depends on `cloud_firestore` in `pubspec.yaml`"), it seems that you didn't deploy your Cloud Function correctly.

As a matter of fact, Cloud Functions are totally independent from your Flutter app (your front-end). It is a **back-end service**. You should deploy it with the Firebase CLI, see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#deploy-functions-to-a-production-environment). Note that the code shall be in the Firebase Project, not in your Flutter project.